# Word search: someone who always manages to see rare things

Tags: single-word-requests

Apparently there is a word for someone who always manages to see "rare" or "low chance" things. Is in the woods and sees animals...looks up and sees a shooting star. Anyone know what this word might be? Someone mentioned it, but couldn't remember what the actual word was.

Comment: Could it be 'lucky'? Please add the sentence it will be used in, and the words you have researched.

Comment: Could it be "liar"?

Comment: Do you mean in the sense of being lucky, or that of being observant and accustomed to spotting wildlife etc.?

Comment: Such a person would be 'observant' and possibly no more than that.

Comment: Second Kate Buntings comment. You have a potentially interesting question here.

Comment: **Never** consult a thesaurus when writing your résumé, especially not our local elugameosaurus here.